# Google Maps JavaScript API request denied

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am always getting an request denied error. The API key I used is green in google cloud console.
I have activated the Places API, the Geocoding API and the Maps javascript API.
This is my code
`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MY_KEY]&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap" async defer></script>`

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What restrictions do you have on the key? What is the exact error message? When is the error thrown?

Comment: Have you enabled billing? I suggest that you also [contact support](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#creating-a-support-case) regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works just fine replacing your api key with the one that google uses on its demo: https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/
It have worked for me even withou key, as shown in the snipet bellow.

I suggest you to revisit your code and if nothing is wrong, try deleting this key and generate another one.

```js
                let map;

        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
                zoom: 8,
            });
        }
```

```css
        #map {
            height: 100%;
        }

        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div id="map" style="height: 100%;"></div>
    <script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&libraries=places,geometry&callback=initMap"
        async defer>
        </script>
```

Comment: Tanks for the answer, also tried without key. Also generated a new key. Same error.